# JavaFX8, SQLite(Embedded) exe, exec jar can't read/update the runtime database

Tags: java, eclipse, sqlite, jdbc, javafx-8

I am creating a simple desktop application using JavaFx8 and SQLite and Eclipse Neon IDE. The Application works fine when launched to test from Eclipse. But If I create an executable jar or a Windows Exe file, it doesn't read/update the database.
Here's the code snippet used for creating and reading database.

```
 private Connection loadPropertiesFileSQLite() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {
    try {
        inputStream = new FileInputStream("databasesqlite.properties");
        properties.load(inputStream);
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        // database path, if it's new database, it will be created in the project folder
        conSQLite = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:Application.db");
        System.out.println("Database Opened Successfully.");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("DDDD");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return conSQLite;
}
```

The connectors and jars I'm using are these:

[image]

The database is created in embedded mode when the user runs the application for the first time.
I have searched and tried scores of combinations from changing the location of database in `DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:Application.db");`
to many other things. Is there anything big that I'm missing here?

Comment: Updated the question with the main issue which is **Database not read/update in executable jar/exe** .

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the properties file for nothing?
there is my config: sqlite-jdbc-3.7.15.jar
//auto commit on the connection.
conSQLite.setAutoCommit(true);

and check if do you have a permission at the file "Application.db".

Comment: Thanks for a quick answer @Rafael Gimenes
Earlier I was using properties file to set the URL for connection but in my tryst to resolve the issue it eventually became a dummy call. My bad.
How do I check the permission and how do I set it in case it's read-only? Please advise.

Answer (score 0):

The key is to use `conSQLite = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite::resource:File:\\{some_path}\\Application.db");`

instead of

```
conSQLite = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:Application.db");
```

Now it works all fine.